# An unknown error has occurred. The form template has been published to the server but it can only be opened in infopath filler

Tags: infopath, 2013

I've created a SP2010 workflow in SP2013 and I want to edit the collect data / approval task workflow forms. Trying Quick Publish in InfoPath Designer results in the following error:

> An unknown error has occurred.  The form template has been published
>   to the server but it can only be opened in infopath filler

It's driving me mad.

I've found and tried the following workarounds:

- Increase execution time in web.config, restart IIS (didn't work)
- Use the highest privileged user (didn't work)
- Make sure no other users have the form checked out (didn't work)
- Re-register the workflow service (didn't work)
- Increase the ViewStateTreshold (didn't work)

I've also found this thread where somebody is claiming this simply cannot be done, but without official confirmation I find that hard to believe: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/42956f82-748f-487e-b9c3-5e0eec5d926d#42956f82-748f-487e-b9c3-5e0eec5d926d

Right now I've set InfoPath logging to Verbose. Here's a small dump of ULS containing the one and only error I could find:

> Entering monitored scope (Request
>   (GET:`http://sharepdevx01:80/demandmanagement/Workflows/Business%20Request%20Management/Assign%20IT%20Architect.xsn?OpenIn=PreferClient&NoRedirect=true&XsnLocation=/demandmanagement/Workflows/Business%20Request%20Management/Assign%20IT%20Architect.xsn`)).
>   Parent No
>       Name=Request (GET:`http://sharepdevx01:80/demandmanagement/Workflows/Business%20Request%20Management/Assign%20IT%20Architect.xsn`?OpenIn=PreferClient&NoRedirect=true&XsnLocation=/demandmanagement/Workflows/Business%20Request%20Management/Assign%20IT%20Architect.xsn)
>       Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|client-com\sp_admin, ClaimsCount=24
>       HTTP Request method: GET
>       Overridden HTTP request method: GET
>       HTTP request URL: /demandmanagement/Workflows/Business%20Request%20Management/Assign%20IT%20Architect.xsn?OpenIn=PreferClient&NoRedirect=true&XsnLocation=/demandmanagement/Workflows/Business%20Request%20Management/Assign%20IT%20Architect.xsn
>       Failed to get document content data. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot complete
>   this function     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd,
>   Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq,
>   SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
>       Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005.
>       Spent 0 ms to bind -1 byte file stream
>       Failure when fetching document. 0x80070012

It's not really clear to me what is causing this.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and this is driving me crazy.<br/>
Some one please help.

Comment: I am trying to resolve above issue from last 2 days but not able to resolve. <br/>
Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue..<br/>
Help about this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by installing the 'Desktop Experience' Windows feature - go to Server Manager > Manage > Add Roles And Features > Features > User Interfaces and Infrastructure > Desktop Experience.  This feature is required to allow SMB-based viewing of SharePoint files (the 'Open in Explorer' option), and it seems InfoPath uses this method of updating files on the server.

I too wasted a day of my life on this, and eventually came up with this solution working through server logs and a procmon of a failure.

Why InfoPath couldn't display a more sensible error is beyond me!

This was on a Server 2012 / SharePoint Server 2013 / SPD 2013 / InfoPath 2013 environment.

Comment: Thank you! I was completely stumped why I couldn't upload my templates on a new SP2013 workflow. You're a life saver!

Comment: TKS From BRAZIL ! It worked for me too!