# The form template has been published to the server, but can only be open in infopath filter

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow

After editing an approval workflow Form in SharePoint Designer - (add button), I can't publish a form to the server. I getting the error:

> The form template has been published to the server, but can only be
>   open in infopath filter.

Comment: You need to install the 'Desktop Experience' Windows feature. Look at this thread. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70695/an-unknown-error-has-occurred-the-form-template-has-been-published-to-the-serve

Comment: But localy, or on the server? I look at server and it has got instaled

Comment: On the machine from which you are publishing infopath form.

Comment: also make sure the form template's compatibility set to Web Browser Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should edit and Cache clear on the local machine. Not in server.